# JointJS ports are not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, lodash, jointjs

I use Ports API and JointJS 2.0. The problem is that i created ports, but they are not active. Port just become part of rect. I can't drag a link from it. Sorry, but i can't setup fiddle link with joint 2.0. I have "joint is not defined" in console. 
Here is code:

```
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#myholder'),
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    model: graph,
    gridSize: 1
});
var port = {
    args: {},
    markup: '<rect width="10" height="10" stroke="red"/>'
};
var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
    attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } },
    ports: {
        groups: {},
        items: [ port ]
    }
});
graph.addCells([rect]);
```

Here is jsfiddle with old [joint](https://codepen.io/mr__brainwash/pen/QQmxyg)

Comment: exact same problem :(

Comment: Question asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51293336/jointjs-ports-are-non-functional/51293830#51293830